# How to populate objects inside a virtual in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have set a virtual query looking like this:

```
UserSchema
    .virtual('user_info')
    .get(function () {
        return { '_id': this._id, 'username': this.username, 'admin': this.admin, 'email': this.email, 'company': this.company, 'image': this.image, 'profile': this.profile };
    });
```

`company` field has the id of the referenced company connected to the user. How can I make it populate this field so that I could get title and other fields `Company` model contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `virtual` returns synchronously, so you don't have time to execute a query and wait for the result in the getter. What you *can* do is [populate a regular object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate), in this case, the return value of your getter:

```
Company.populate(
    someUser.user_info,   // This is a plain object, not a Document.
    {
        path:  "company", 
        model: "company"  // If you specify the model here, 
                          // it doesn't technically matter what 
                          // model you use on line one...
    },
    function(err, user_info) {

        console.log("User info with populated company", user_info);
        console.log("Company name", user_info.company.name);

    }
);
```

Comment: I have replaced all cases where `someUser.user_info` virtual method was used in my app with a query like you advised and it seemed to work, thanks!